# How to manually configure routing instead of File based routing in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, url-routing, next-router

We know in Next.js, We express application structure in the file system. When a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route. For example:

pages/about.js → /about

pages/blog.js → /blog

pages/index.js → /

But I want to manually select the component file to render for each path. For example in the following code I want to render Service Component if my path URL is **localhost:3000/about**, I don't want to make my filename according to the routing pathname.

```
 <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <Service />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
 </Switch>
```

How can i solve this issue without using React Router/Reach-Router.Is there any other options available without installing any 3rd party library?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Maybe you need https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js

Comment: Thanks @nghiepit , But this wont solve my problem.

Comment: @nghiepit, after.js looked promising to me, but it doesn't seem like there's anything happening on that repo. Perhaps its not being pursued anymore?